# Pullback with $\omega = ze^{xy} dx \wedge dy$

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $\omega = ze^{xy} dx \wedge dy$ be a $2$-form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^2_{\ne 0} \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be the map $\varphi(u,v) = \left( \frac{u}{v}, \frac{v}{u}, uv \right)$. Find $\varphi^*\omega$.

In [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(differential_geometry)#Pullback_of_differential_forms) it's described that the pullback of a $k$-form is $$(\varphi ^{*}\alpha )_{x}(X_{1},\ldots ,X_{k})=\alpha _{\varphi (x)}(d\varphi _{x}(X_{1}),\ldots ,d\varphi _{x}(X_{k})).$$ So since I'm dealing with a $2$-form I would have that $$(\varphi^*\omega)_x(v_1,v_2) = \omega_{\varphi(x)}(d\varphi_x(v_1), d\varphi_x(v_2)).$$ Now If I understood the article correctly the $d\varphi$ is the Jacobian matrix so the question arising here is that what is meant by $d\varphi_\color{red}{x}$ and is $d\varphi_x(v_1)$ supposed to be a matrix-vector product?

Comment: $d\phi_x$ is probably the Jacobian evaluated at $x$ (remember that its entries depend on $x$) and $d\phi_x(v_1)$ the matrix-vector product. Don't take this as guaranteed though, because tbh I haven't worked with differential forms in a long time

Comment: In practice, it's easiest to think of this is $(x,y,z) = \varphi(u,v)$ so in particular $x = \frac{u}{v}, y = \frac{v}{u}, z = uv$. Given this, you get $dx = d(\frac{u}{v}) = \frac{v du - u dv}{v^2}$. You can figure it out similarly for $dy$. And then $\varphi^*(ze^{xy}) = (uv)e^{\frac{u}{v} \frac{v}{u}}$

Comment: If you really want to use the Jacobian, just note that these derivatives are exactly what will fill in the Jacobian. I can expand on this in a response if needed!

Answer (score 1):

Denote the domain of $\varphi$ by $U$. Take $v_1,v_2\in T_xU$. We are defining $\varphi^*\omega$ on tangent vectors based at $x$ by $(\varphi^*\omega)_x = \omega_{\varphi(x)}(d\varphi_x v_1,d\varphi_x v_2)$; here, $d\phi_x: T_xU \to T_{\varphi(x)} \Bbb{R}^3$ is the Jacobian evaluated at the point $x$. I.e. instead of being a matrix of smooth functions, it is a matrix of numbers. Since $v_1$ and $v_2$ are based at $x$, this is the only sensible definition.

Comment: Should $v_1$ and $v_2$ be taken in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$? Also $x$ is not given in the problem statement so how can this matrix-vector product be computed? @alekos-robotis

Comment: The tangent space to $U$ at $x$ is a $2$-dimensional space.